# Excel 2016 if Cell E2 = "QTR1" or "QTR2" etc.... (drop down list) get data from Sheet'name' cell F9

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have workbook with one tab used to get data from 14 different tabs, each tab has a column QTR1, QTR2, QTR3, QTR4. These columns have questions in A1 to A29.

I have 14 areas add data into their tab each quarter.  On the main TAB I would like to have a drop down list in CELL E2.  When this changes it grabs the QTR1, 2, 3 or 4 data from each of the 14 other tabs and places them in the correct columns on the first tab.

I was thinking if I do a simple `IF` statement in each cell `=IF(E2="QTR1"` *THEN F4 OF MAIN TAB = "Albatross F4*).  I would then just change the cell or tab ranges to suit = long and not the best but it seems to be the easiest solution without using too many formulas that no-one will understand.

Don't know if `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP` up would work as I am trying to copy a cell from one tab to the main on dependent on cell E2.

How do I add my workbook for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out this formula it works, is there an easier way to do this?

=IF(E2="QTR 1",' Albatross 2019'!F4, IF(E2="QTR 2",' Albatross 2019'!I4, IF(E2="QTR 3",' Albatross 2019'!L4, IF(E2="QTR 4",' Albatross 2019'!O4))))

It work, I just have to edit all of the cells to reference the correct TABs and Cell values, so its ok, clunky but at least it works.

Thanks for reading. If you have a better way, I am all eyes and ears.....